# Stop camera capture thread but couldn't release

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt

I am using qthread to show image captured from an usb camera.

The problem is after terminating the thread using:

`th.terminate()`

Camera light still on indicating it is still being used. (skipped to release capture)

Tried to do:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.release()
```

After terminate, but the problem remains.

```
if(self.monitoringToggle == False):
    self.monitoringToggle = True
    self.monitoringButton.setText("Stop Monitoring")
    self.th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
    self.th.start()

else:
    self.monitoringToggle = False
    self.monitoringButton.setText("Monitoring")
    self.th.terminate()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.release()
    qImg = QImage("white_background.png")
    self.videoLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(qImg))

class MonitoringThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while(True):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
        cap.release()
```

Comment: Your thread runs a forever loop, if you terminate thread, cap.release() will not be called. You should use a bool variable to control the loop. When terminate thread, send signal to set this variable to False, loop will exit and thread will be terminated.

Comment: Right, I think so too. Need to study signals.